# How to connect YouBot with a Laptop

Tags: ros, youbot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to connect my Laptop with KUKA youbot. But, I am failed to do so. So please help me to configure it.

1. where should the EtherCAT connect to the youbot.
2. should i start the youbot PC on
3. or just set the youbot Motor on

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214742/how-to-connect-youbot-with-a-laptop/) by [sawa](https://answers.ros.org/users/23381/sawa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-07-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My company has the Youbot. I have never used it but what I know is:

The Ethercat on the Youbot is of course connected to the PC inside the robot (running the Ethercat Master) and the ARM(s) and the motors for the wheels.

I guess ROS has to run on the Youbot PC, so yes you need to enable it, also the Motors you need (if you want the Robot
to move). Also add a wireless network adapter to the Youbot PC and connect over ssh to it.

Install ROS on your PC and decide where you wil run the ROS master.

On the PC (either yours or the Youbot) with the master you set up the master URI as http://localhost:11311 (you do not have to do anything there) on the other one you set it to http://hostname-of-the-other:11311.

Be sure to have either the hostnames in the host files, or a DNS running.

Regards,

Christian

---

Originally posted by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) with karma: 1376 on 2015-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sawa](https://answers.ros.org/users/23381/sawa/) on 2015-08-04**:
Dear Christian,

Thank you for your reply. I will follow all the steps and will let you know.

Best regards,

Arif